# How to reference a class method instead of a function in a callback function in PHP/Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

**Disclaimer**, I've only been doing Wordpress/PHP for a few weeks, so feel free to REALLY break things down for me.

I've been working on building a settings page for my custom Wordpress plugin. My plugin has all of its functions living in classes, so I am doing things like this:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'custom_func'));
```

instead of

```
add_action('init', 'custom_func');
```

I *think* this is working because the second argument for add_action accepts an **array** OR the **string** name of a function OR an **anonymous function**.

My current issue is that I can't get this to work for my settings page.

The code:

```
public function plugin_admin_init () {

    //Register group of options
    register_setting( 'exp_wp_plugin_options', 'exp_wp_plugin_options', array( $this, 'plugin_options_validate' ) );

    //Add a section to group
    add_settings_section('exp_wp_plugin_main', 'Main Settings', function () {

    //plugin_settings_text
    echo '<p>Main description of this section here.</p>';

       }, $this->screen );

    //Add a field to the section
    add_settings_field('exp_wp_plugin_text_string', 'Plugin Text Input', array( $this, 'plugin_setting_string' ), $this->screen, 'plugin_main');

   }

public function plugin_setting_string() {

    $options = get_option('plugin_options');

    echo "<input id='plugin_text_string' name='plugin_options[text_string]' size='40' type='text' value='{$options[ 'text_string' ]}' />";

}
```

1. The `register_settings` function call allows me to pass the array($this, 'func_name') syntax
2. The second function call, `add_settings_section`, is working using an anonymous function (but I'd rather move this to another method if possible).
3. The third function, `add_settings_field`, is failing using the array($this, 'func_name') syntax, and the error being thrown is that it's looking for a string.

These methods are part of WP's Settings API. I'm not sure if this is a PHP problem, or a Wordpress problem, but if anyone can tell me how to get this working, I'd appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** This is the error my IDE (PHP Storm) is throwing:

> Expected string, got array. Invocation parameter types are not
>   compatible with declared.

Comment: Hi, what is the exact error message you are seeing?

Comment: @AlexanderGottlieb I added the error message ^^

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using? In the [current source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1241) the third argument is properly type hinted as `callable`, so PHPStorm shouldn't give you a warning about it. This was changed on [Feb 23rd, 2016](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php?rev=36642#L1174), before that it was indeed type hinted as `string`. This change was first included in Wordpress 4.5, released in April 2016.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Ah makes sense. I'm working on a corporate legacy tool that uses 4.2.2. I can accept that as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm bases its warning on the type hinting set in the method's docblock comment. As of Wordpress 4.5, the docblock for the `add_settings_field()` function has been fixed to indicate that it accepts a `callable`, before that it used to indicate `string`.

If you look at the function's docblock comment in [Wordpress 4.4.10 (last 4.4.x version)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.10/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php?rev=40762#L1210) and [Wordpress 4.5](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php?rev=37181#L1212), you'll notice that they changed it from `@param string $callback` to `@param callable $callback`. You may also notice that the inner workings of the function were not changed, the actual implementation has always accepted a callable.

It's probably safe to ignore this warning from PHPStorm, but I recommend you try it out on a non-production environment first. If PHP itself is fine with it, you can choose to [suppress the warning](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/suppressing-inspections.html#d337696e68) in PHPStorm.

The better option would be to upgrade Wordpress to a recent version (if possible). Wordpress powers a large portion of the internet, so it's a very popular target for hackers. If you're running an older version, there ***will*** be [vulnerabilities in your site](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/version_id-185073/Wordpress-Wordpress-4.2.2.html) that can be abused if a hacker ever decides to target your company or is just randomly looking for servers to add to their botnet.

Comment: Thank you! This is great. And also builds my case as to why we need an upgrade!